# How to contact a member directly?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to contact a member directly. After going through help topics, etc. etc. I found nothing. All I can do is get a profile. Same for the Moderators...

Any help would be appreciated.

Tom

PS There are no appropriate tags to ask a site question so now I'm fighting with that.

Comment: Assume no one on the site wants to be contacted directly. If a member wants to be contacted, they will put contact information on their profile page. Alternately, you can ask someone to contact *you* in a comment.

Comment: Don't worry about the down votes, in *meta sites* they don't actually count against you. Instead, they are just a way for people to express an opinion about the question without writing a comment or answer. Down votes here may only mean that people don't think it's a good idea to try to contact users directly if they haven't posted any contact information in their profiles.

Comment: Mind if I ask *why* you want to do this?

Answer (score 9):

Stack Exchange is not a social network and is not intended or designed for contacting other people directly.

If you have questions about using the site, ask on Meta Space Exploration.  I have already migrated your question there.  You need 5 reputation to participate in Meta.

If there is a problem with a particular question, comment, or answer, and a moderator should look at this, you can flag this question when you have at least 15 reputation.

You can also contact users or moderators using Stack Exchange Chat if you have at least 20 reputation.

Some users may have a link to a blog, website, twitter, email, or other contact information on their profile page.

For other specific concerns of a nature that should not be discussed publicly, you can contact the community team with the "contact us" button, but not the moderators unless they contact you first, which they will only do if there is a problem.